# Как из массива объектов сделать один единственный объект?

Tags: javascript

```js
    let ascii = [];
    for (let i = 48; i <= 122; i++) {
        let ascii_el = String.fromCharCode(i);
        ascii.push({ i, ascii_el })
    }
```

---

Внутри - decimal ascii таблицы и ее char

```
 [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let ascii = {} 
for( let i = 48; i <= 122; i++ ){ 
  ascii[ i ] = String.fromCharCode(i); 
}  

console.log( ascii );
```

А если уже откуда-то получен такой массив, можно переделать его так:

```js
let ascii = [];
for (let i = 48; i <= 122; i++) {
  let ascii_el = String.fromCharCode(i);
  ascii.push({i, ascii_el});
}

let obj = {};
for( let i = 0; i < ascii.length; i++ ){
  obj[ ascii[ i ].i ] = ascii[ i ].ascii_el;
}
console.log( obj );
```